# Using beamer template system without beamer?

Tags: beamer

I particularly like the Beamer template system, in particular because of the hierarchical relationships between different settings, the separation between fonts, color, and style of each item, and the ability to provide multiple choices of predefined settings for an item.

So I was thinking about making a document class for a thesis what would be customizable in the same way.

It would be nice to have a separate `beamer-templates` package similar to the standalone `pgfkeys` package that one can use to have `pgf`-style key value parameters without using `pgf` itself. But as far as I know there is no such package.

So is it possible to use the bare bones templating system of `beamer` without `beamer` itself?

Comment: What sort of answer are you after here: 'yes' seems a bit short but a full package is a bit much. The LaTeX team are very much thinking about 'templates' in this regard: one of the jobs for 'real soon now'!

Comment: Well, for example, can the Beamer template code be extracted fairly easy should I want to try? Or, maybe it is fairly easy to emulate with some clever use of pgfkeys..

Comment: Or, can it be signaled to the Beamer team in some way so they can release it as a standalone package in the near future?

Comment: No it is not fairly easy. E.g. beamer can customize an itemize list only because it has redefined itemize. And similar for all other objects. Imho quite some work is needed to get a usefull system.

Comment: Of course! But I was talking about the template system itself, i.e. the `\setbeamertemplate` commands and the like, with the handling of the hierarchy of items and all these things. I'm not talking about the concrete items that customize the appearance of LaTeX environments.

Comment: Perhaps with `xtemplate`, but definitely not out of the box!

Comment: You may try to include the file `beamerbasetemplates.sty`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in comments, the `beamer` template system 'set up' in all contained in one file, `beamerbasetemplates.sty`. One could extract the concepts from that file in a relatively straightforward way. (The file itself depends on the overlay concept in `beamer` so cannot be loaded directly without some set up/modification.)

However, most of the 'real' work of a template/style sheet concept is putting the appropriate 'hooks' into all of the definitions used in a document, not the code to define templates. In `beamer` this is done by (re)defining the entire document architecture to include `\usebeamertemplate` and so forth in the appropriate places. This is the 'real work' and is non-trivial. The LaTeX team are actively looking at these concepts: current experiments such as [`xtemplate`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xtemplate) or the ['LaTeX Data Base'](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/tree/master/l3trial/l3ldb) (unreleased) are useful but somewhat old: in light of ideas including the `beamer` template approach, CSS, `pgfkeys`, *etc.*, the team are working on new/modified ideas which should address this area.

(Note that the '`beamer` team is currently me, and as I'm also involved in LaTeX3 work I'm more keen on a new approach informed by `beamer` than simply extracting out the current code in a way that is unlikely to be widely taken up.)